# Is there a way to read stock charts with python?

Tags: python, charts

I would like my python program to look at a Bitcoin chart and search the price of Bitcoin at a certain time. So it should search that time in the x-axis of the chart and print the price of one Bitcoin at that time.
The chart I would like to be read by python:
https://www.bitstamp.net/markets/btc/eur/

Comment: Yes. Many folks use BeautifulSoup for this. How to scrape the particular site you want to scrape will take some work, but if you get stuck with a specific question (this one is much too broad in it's current form) feel free to shoot it out here to StackOverflow. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance when the time comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a good resource online that outlines how you can extract data from bitmap graphs using python. I have linked the article below:[Reading Bitmap with Python](https://medium.com/@sanic_the_hedgefond/scraping-information-out-of-raw-pixeldata-with-python-4bf34641b6c3)